# Parsing json data in phonegap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-desktop-app

Following is my json data URL
http://bluestonesolutions.in/Connect4mJson/GetEmployees.svc/getnotice?InstanceId=604&EnoticeType=Flash%20News&UserID=112730&IsGlobalNotice=0

I want display data in table using jquery Mobile for Phonegap. I can fetch data easily but can display in mobile.

Here is working example. Please guide me how to parse it for phonegap

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://bluestonesolutions.in/Connect4mJson/GetEmployees.svc/getnotice?InstanceId=604&EnoticeType=Flash%20News&UserID=112730&IsGlobalNotice=0',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        crossDomain: true,
        success : function(data) {      
            document.write('<table width="400" height="288" align="center"  style="border:5px solid #10A3D8; ">')
            $.each(data, function() {
                console.log(this.Subject);
                document.write('<tr style="background:#D4D2D2;" >')
                document.write('<td style="color:#041DB3;">'+'Subject:-</td>')
                document.write('<td style="color:#041DB3;">'+this.Subject+'</td>')
                document.write('</tr>')
                document.write('<tr style="background:#04A273;">')
                document.write('<td>'+'Description:-</td>')
                document.write('<td>'+this.ENoticeDescription+'</td>')
                document.write('</tr>')
            });
            document.write('<table>');          
            // open console debugging tools on google and see the parse value
        },
        error : function() {}
    });
});
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I can make out `document.write('') document.write('') document.write`, what on Earth is that O_o This erases the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this to parse JSON

```
jQuery.parseJSON()
```

Comment: Nope. No need, OP is using `dataType : 'JSON'` (hard to read, I know). Besides, `jQuery.parseJSON()` doesn't do anything on its own. This is not a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON like 
var JsonStringify_ExecResData = JSON.stringify(data);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JsonStringify_ExecResData);

and like

localStorage.setItem("userEmail", userEmail);

You can set the parameters and get in another page like

localStorage.setItem("userEmail", userEmail);

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in Phonegap, but this is how you'd create/populate a table in jQuery for your specific scenario. You may then append the table to an exising element on the page or like I did, to the body (as it's a demo). Adapt this code to suit your needs, such as replace everything between `success : function(data) {` and `})` with my code except the `var dat = [....];`

```js
var data = [{"CategoryName":"Flash News","DisplayOrder":"0","ENoticeDescription":"","ENoticeId":19619,"NoticeDocument":"","Subject":"Singing competitions will be conducted this Month, interested candidates can come to office room and enroll.","createddate":"12 Jun 2014","noticedate":"6\/12\/2014 12:00:00 AM"},{"CategoryName":"Flash News","DisplayOrder":"0","ENoticeDescription":"","ENoticeId":19623,"NoticeDocument":"","Subject":"Flowers day celebrations will be conducted on 1st Saturday of next Month, Students are instructed to bring 5 different Flowers.","createddate":"12 Jun 2014","noticedate":"6\/12\/2014 12:00:00 AM"},{"CategoryName":"Flash News","DisplayOrder":"0","ENoticeDescription":"","ENoticeId":19624,"NoticeDocument":"","Subject":"Painting competitions for Senior Program will be conducted on 30th of this month.","createddate":"12 Jun 2014","noticedate":"6\/12\/2014 12:00:00 AM"},{"CategoryName":"Flash News","DisplayOrder":"0","ENoticeDescription":"Debate competition for Senior class students will be conducted on 2nd of April month, interested students contact Head of Senior Program Staff.","ENoticeId":19660,"NoticeDocument":"","Subject":"Senior Program - Debate Competition","createddate":"12 Jun 2014","noticedate":"6\/12\/2014 12:00:00 AM"}];

var $table = $('<table width="400" height="288" align="center"  style="border:5px solid #10A3D8;">');
var $trs = $();
$.each(data, function() {
    var $tr = $("<tr/>").css("background", "#D4D2D2");
    var $td = $("<td/>").css("color", "#041DB3").text("Subject:");
    $tr.append($td);
    $td = $("<td/>").css("color", "#041DB3").text(this.Subject);
    $tr.append($td);
    $trs = $trs.add($tr);
    
    $tr = $("<tr/>").css("background", "#04A273");
    $td = $("<td/>").css("color", "#041DB3").text("Description:");
    $tr.append($td);
    $td = $("<td/>").css("color", "#041DB3").text(this.ENoticeDescription);
    $tr.append($td);
    $trs = $trs.add($tr);
});
$table.empty().append($trs);
$("body").empty().append($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use CSS classes instead of `.css("prop", "value")` as it's against performance when you have 100s of elements. It's okay for this specific case as the data is not that huge. But, I'd still suggest that you use classes.